# Printing list permutation

Tags: c#, list, permutation

I have (in C#) a list of objects (each one containing a list) and I'd like to print out every permutation of the items in the objects' lists. Each iteration would use one item from each list. What would be the most efficient way to achieve this? Pseudo code is welcomed.

```
public class Detail {

    public int type;
    public List<String> codes;

    public Detail(int i){

        this.type = i;
        this.codes = new List<String>();

    }

}
```

Later on...

```
List<Detail> ListOfDetail = new List<Detail>();
foreach(Field i in listBox.Items)
    ListOfDetail.Add(new Detail(i));
```

The code list, which is assigned from a db, can be anything from 2 to 250.

If I had 3 objects (A, B, and C), with A holding 1,2,3, B holding 4,5,6, and C holding 7,8,9, I'd want it to print the following:

```
147
148
149
157
158
159
167
etc...
```

Comment: Could you provide a rough code outline of the object model? The description is slightly vague, I don't believe you'd want to see guesses for answers.

Comment: Ok, so with your update, you have an arbitrarily long list of Details, each with an arbitrarily long list of strings. Eric Lippert blogged about *[a cartesian product of arbitrarily many sequences](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx)* and it may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm following you correctly, you want something like this:

**UPDATED:**

```
foreach(var secondaryList in primaryListOfObjects) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var str in secondaryList) {
        sb.Append(str);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```